# Program error: Invalid column index

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

What I should do is to create a Java stored procedure and later call it from Java program.

I am having problems executing the JAVA program - JDBCPiemers (below) with 1 parameter (I need to get out the String Nosaukums). Error: "Invalid column name".

I am sure there is problems with returning String Razotajs as there are only 1 parameter in the procedure defined, however I do not know how to fix it.

Calling out the procedure in ORACLE works fine.

This is my stored procedure which I have loaded in database.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BeerBeer {

  public static void getBreweryInfo (int Raz_ID) 
    throws SQLException 
    { String sql = 
      "SELECT Nosaukums FROM Alus_razotaji WHERE ID = ?";//vaicajums
    try { Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:"); // Izveidojam savienojumu ar datubāzi
      PreparedStatement apstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      apstmt.setInt(1, Raz_ID); 
      ResultSet rset = apstmt.executeQuery();// SQL vaicājuma izpildīšana

      rset.close();
      apstmt.close(); //Savienojuma aizvēršana
      } 
    catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage()); //Kļūdu izvadīsana
    }  
  }
}
```

I have created a following package with oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BeerBeer AS
PROCEDURE getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number);
END BeerBeer;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BeerBeer AS
PROCEDURE getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number) AS Language Java
NAME 'BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(int)';
END BeerBeer;
```

This is my Java program in which I call out the procedure. However I cannot get it working. I am getting error: "Invalid column index"

```
package client;

import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCPiemers {
    // Norādam URL draiverim un datu bāzei
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
    // Izveidojam norādi uz datu bāzes lietotājvārdu un paroli
    static final String USER = "SYSTEM";
    static final String PASS = "asdasd";
    private String sql;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            //Reģistrējam JDBC draiveri
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Izveidojam savienojumu ar datubazi ...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            // Vaicājuma izveide
            System.out.println("Komandas veidosana...");
            String SQL = "{CALL BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo (?)}";
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(SQL);
            int Raz_ID = 4;
            stmt.setInt(1, Raz_ID);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            System.out.println("Izpildam JAVA glabajamo proceduru ...");
            // Vaicājuma izpilde
            stmt.execute();
            //Izgustam Alus_razotaja nosaukumu ar getXXX metodi.
            String Razotajs = stmt.getString(2);
            System.out.println("Izvadam rezultatus ...");
            System.out.println("Identifikatoram NR. " +Raz_ID + " atbilst Alus_Razotajs ar nosaukumu  '" + Razotajs + "'" );            
            stmt.close();
            conn.close(); }
            catch(SQLException se) {
                //Kludu apstrade JDBC
                se.printStackTrace(); }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //Kludu apstrade klasei Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            finally {
                // Bloks, lai aizvērtu resursus
                try {if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close(); }
            catch(SQLException se2) {} 
                try {if(conn!=null)
                conn.close(); }
                catch(SQLException se) {se.printStackTrace(); }
                //finally bloka beigas
            } // try 
            System.out.println("Darbu beidzam."); }}
```

Comment: Is `Nosaukums` a valid column name in your database?

Comment: try wuith String Razotajs = stmt.getString(1);

Comment: @MathiasGhys Yeah, the column name is correct. Procedure is working when calling it from ORACLE, however I cannot get it to work with java program.

Comment: There is only one placeholder `?` in the string: `{CALL BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo (?)}`, so you cannot register 2 parameters. Second, the oracle procedure `getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number);` declares one parameter without `IN/OUT` modifier, so default mode for this parameter is `IN`, which allows only for passing a value to the procedure, but not return a value to the caller. If you want to return a value from the procedure, you must declare an `OUT` parameter, or `IN OUT`, see details here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#i4107

Comment: @kordirko - doesn't the Java stored procedure mean it needs to be a function though, rather than a procedure with an `OUT` parameter? (I've put answer to that effect in the original question, but I might be wrong!)